# How to write printed value from one sheet to newly created one

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I am new to Python so only just getting to grips with it and would really appreciate some help as I can't figure out how to write the values from file A into file B.

I would like to:

1. filter the values of column D from 'mf_mar_2018.xls' (filter of 'saxon')
2. write the found values into a new file called 'saxons.xls'

I am able to get the non-filtered values and print them in Terminal.

My script is below:

```
#import the writer
import xlwt
#open the spreadsheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
#add a sheet named "Club BFA ranking"
worksheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("Club BFA ranking")
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "Ranking"
worksheet1.write(0, 0, "Ranking")
#in cell 0,1 (second cell of the first row) write "Name"
worksheet1.write(0, 1, "Name")
#save and create the spreadsheet file
workbook.save("saxons.xls")

#import the reader
import xlrd
#open the rankings spreadsheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook('mf_mar_2018.xls')
#open the first sheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
#print the values in the second column of the first sheet
print first_sheet.col_values(1)
```

Comment: What is saxon exactly? Is it a part of string in the cells in column D? Or do you want all values from column D?

Comment: good question - saxon is a club.  the file that i am reading from is a national list of rankings, what i want to do is filter the athletes by club and then write the filtered results to the new sheet. so 'saxon' itself would be a string found in a number of cells in column d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
name = []
rank = []
for i in range(first_sheet.nrows):
    #print(first_sheet.cell_value(i,3)) 
    if('Saxon' in first_sheet.cell_value(i,3)):  
        name.append(first_sheet.cell_value(i,2))
        rank.append(first_sheet.cell_value(i,8))    
        print('a')
for j in range(len(name)):
    worksheet1.write(j+1,0,rank[j])
    worksheet1.write(j+1,1,name[j])


workbook.save("saxons.xls")
```

Comment: thank you - it doesn't seem to do anything.  do i just add it to the bottom of my script?

Comment: Yes and remove 'workbook.save("saxons.xls")' and add it at the end.

Comment: i still can't seem to get it to work - the filter doesn't get applied if i print the values in terminal and i still can't seem to print to the other sheet

Comment: Could you show what the 'mf_mar_2018.xls' sheet looks like?

Comment: sure thing - i can't seem to add an image but you can find it here: https://www.britishfencing.com/results-rankings/mens-foil-ranking-archive/ it's the march link

Comment: Please check the edited code. Paste this after your script.